# Oracle VM VirtualBox LinuxMint zoomed very far out

Tags: linux, linux-mint, virtualbox, fonts, size

I recently downloaded Oracle VM VirtualBox on my MacBook and am using it for Linux Mint.  When I go onto the Linux Mint VM, all of the fonts and applications are extremely tiny and almost impossible to read. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the Guest Additions installed.

View > Auto-resize Guest Display

View > Scale > 200%